# Как добавить .exe файл в автозагрузку средствами Golang

Tags: golang, автозагрузка

**Как мне добавить приложение в автозагрузку средствами Golang?** 
Какое есть решение для Windows и для Linux, я знаю что универсального решения нету, именно отдельные решения для той или иной ОС. Смотрел в сторону https://github.com/ProtonMail/go-autostart, но у меня 64 битная ОС и у меня оно не компилируется, ошибка `cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in` альтернативных вариантов я не вижу так как это единственный пакет для автозагрузки средствами `golang`

Comment: Это сильно зависит от того, какая ОС.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov windows 32/64 bit / Linux i386/amd64

Comment: Универсального решения нет. Решение под конкретную ОС не зависит от языка.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я понимаю что универсального решения нету, можно просто проверять при помощи GOOS какая ОС стоит. Если виндовс то использовать решение для виндовс, если линукс то для линукса.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я обновил вопрос.

Comment: Пакет не нужен, достаточно уметь писать в реестр или даже копировать файл в каталог Startups